# Deadlifting during and after MCL class Ii

Tags: squats, deadlifts, knee-pain

I have not done a squat or a deadlift in close to 4 weeks.  I overtrained and hurt MCL- based on what I read online I think it was a class II tear. I haven't had any pain for my re than a week. If I body weight squat I do feel a little discomfort. My questions would be the following:

1. Should I wrap my knees during squat and deadlift?
2. What is an optimal foot position for relieving sheer force on the mcl?

Comment: What about getting a concrete diagnosis rather than guessing from some online reading?

Comment: Dont do DEADLIFT, SQUAT all had injury and nobody expose it, they kept it secret by not telling injury's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes you need to be seen.

- Knee braces i.e. CopperFIT do nothing.  If you're orthopedically evaluated - if indicated - they'll recommend a brace.
- A grade II MCL sprain means it's partially torn *(to what degree?)*
  however it sounds like this was a self diagnosis

---

### Realize a few things here:

- Collagen is avascular and consists of fibers that run parallel to each other.  *(this provides it's tensile strength)*.
- It heels slowly and if you're not receiving proper rehab the fibers
  heal in a random "spaghetti" like pattern.  As the majority of fibers are no longer parallel it provides little support and a full tear becomes likely.

---

- With an MCL tear medial movements should be painful - avoid
  knock-knee positions *(genu valgum)*.
- Your foot position doesn't really matter in this case. This does not change the fact your MCL is still partially torn.
- Your knee position is what you need to watch.  Minimize lower extremity movements toward the midline of your body.

Answer (score 0):

I am no doctor but

1. I don't think that knee wraps are used for the purpose of supporting damaged joints. If body weight squats cause discomfort weighted squats should be avoided. Also I think knee wraps aren't that good for recovery because they restrict blood flow in the area.
2. I am not qualified to answer this question.

That said I cannot stress enough how careful you should be with your knees. Ligaments grow slowly and take longer to repair than muscle. I seriously advise you to see a medical proffessional and enjoy some low impact and "easy on the joints" sports. Swimming, cycling (not off-road), etc. I have a friend who tore a ligament and it is something I would urge you to avoid.

Comment: That's good advice. I actually had no diagnosis - so it's pure conjecture. I don't want to make it worse.